# Python : convert a float encoded as a byte string (from PyTorch) to an int

Tags: python, byte, pytorch

I have converted an output from PyTorch using `.detach().numpy()` which produces this kind of data :

`b'0.06722715'`

which is a `byte` type according to `type()` from Python. How can I convert this to an integer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (explaination in code comments). You can convert 0.06 to an integer but you'll get a zero. Did you mean float?

```
#byte
b = b'0.06722715'
# to string
s = b.decode()
# to float
f = float(s)
# to integer
i = int(f)
print("Float", f)
print("Integer", i)
```

or simply

```
be_float = float(b.decode())
print (be_float)
```